# How to efficiently append new data to table in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena that is created from a csv file stored in S3 and I am using Lambda to query it. But I have incoming data being processed by the lambda function and want to append a new row to the existing table in Athena. How can I do this? Because I saw in documentation that Athena prohibits some SQL statements like `INSERT INTO` and `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are adding new data you can save the new data file into the same folder (prefix/key) that the table is in reading from. Athena will read from all files in this folder, the format of the new file just needs to be the same as the existing one.

Comment: Correct! To clarify: Athena is read-only. So, you need to update the data in the pace where Athena is reading.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Would I have to run a query in Athena to recreate a new table, or will Athena be able to detect that the data file is different and automatically create new table?

Comment: Athena actually looks for all files within the nominated PATH. Any new files and any updated files will automatically be included. It doesn't need to detect whether a file is different -- it simply reads whatever files are present at the time when the query is run.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So if I want to append new data from lambda function, then I would have to download the file from S3, add new data, and then upload back to S3 with same name as original file? Or is there something I'm missing? Because it seems like it would be slow for large datasets

Comment: No, simply add a new file in the location (directory) that you nominate in the Athena `CREATE TABLE` command. Athena reads multiple files in parallel, so it actually works more efficiently on many files that one larger file.

Comment: Where are the docs related to this behavior?